# transactional sqlite? in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am writing a prototype application. Right now some things fail such as inserting a non unique column. In this case i would like to rollback everything i have did. How do i do that?
I also notice in sqlite i need to commit the data, in C# it seems to do it automatically which makes me suspect there is an automatic rollback option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rollback:  It looks like what you are looking for is the command text "INSERT OR ROLLBACK ... "

Transaction:  sqlite automatically puts each command into its own transaction unless you specifically state when to begin.
EDIT:  TML explains this portion a bit more in-depth in his answer

example of explicitly opening/committing a transaction is:

```
using (DbTransaction dbTrans = myDBConnection.BeginTransaction())
{
     using (DbCommand cmd = myDBConnection.CreateCommand())
     {
         ...
     }
     dbTrans.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[SQLite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) says:

> The changes to locking and concurrency
>   control in SQLite version 3 also
>   introduce some subtle changes in the
>   way transactions work at the SQL
>   language level. By default, SQLite
>   version 3 operates in autocommit mode.
>   In autocommit mode, all changes to the
>   database are committed as soon as all
>   operations associated with the current
>   database connection complete.
>
> The SQL command "BEGIN TRANSACTION"
>   (the TRANSACTION keyword is optional)
>   is used to take SQLite out of
>   autocommit mode. Note that the BEGIN
>   command does not acquire any locks on
>   the database. After a BEGIN command, a
>   SHARED lock will be acquired when the
>   first SELECT statement is executed. A
>   RESERVED lock will be acquired when
>   the first INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement is executed. No EXCLUSIVE
>   lock is acquired until either the
>   memory cache fills up and must be
>   spilled to disk or until the
>   transaction commits. In this way, the
>   system delays blocking read access to
>   the file file until the last possible
>   moment.

Comment: yeah, SQLLite really forces you to use "transactional" queries instead of the bad habit of sending them one by one.