# sqlite exception when read and write concurrently using c# application

Tags: c#, sqlite

In my c# application i am facing an exception as below,
Get item failed, reason:Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The above exception happens when two url's called simultaneously. which is decribed below,

http://localhost.:8081/statistics/postdata?sessionId=utviuataoe
http://localhost.:8081/item/detail/2916/content

where postdata writes data to sqlite database which is background process everytime . At the same time need to be displayed some images to the end user then the exception occurs.

Database used is sqlite. For writing data to sqlite below code is used.

```
if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                Open(DataFile);

            using (SQLiteTransaction dbtrans = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {

                using (cmd.Connection = conn)
                {


                    try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText;
                        cmd.Transaction = dbtrans;
                        ireturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dbtrans.Commit();
                        cmd.Dispose();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
```

For reading data below code is used,

```
 public SQLiteDataReader ExecuteSQL(String sqlExpr)
        {


            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                Open(DataFile);

            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText = sqlExpr + ";PRAGMA read_uncommitted = 1;";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                return cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }


        }
```

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: did you try using single client. and make sure the directory has read/write permission enabled where sqlite db file is located. @Sangeetha

Comment: Read/write permisson is enabled.

Comment: what about running a single client rather concurrent use.

Comment: Dont use SQLite in a concurrent situaltion. it behaves like file nothing else. See answer of Hugues Van Landeghem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863595/sqlite-firebird-does-any-of-them-support-multiple-concurrent-write-access