# c# - Commit to sqlite after insert row

Tags: sqlite, c#-3.0

I am writing my first c# windows form app which I will be using for personal use. It is a utility app for my astrophotography hobby.  I have had to recover my code a number of times from a repository just because I messed things up so much.  The sqlite db has been pretty beat up and I "think" I may messed up the indexes.  I can rebuild it, there is no data there that I can't recreate.

The logic of the code is that I check to see if I have recorded a target already to the db before I try to do an insert.  This is the code I use to see if I have already recorded a target that I am working on in the app..

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=..\\..\\Astrophotography DataBase\\Astrophotography.db;Version=3;";

public bool QueryATI(string strTargetName, string[] arrEquipment)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        bool result = false; 
        SQLiteCommand command =
             new SQLiteCommand("SELECT ATI_TargetName, ATI_Telescope_Lens_Used FROM Astro_Target_Imaged WHERE ATI_TargetName = @Target", conn);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Target", strTargetName));
        using (SQLiteDataReader TargetReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int i = 0;
            
            if (TargetReader.HasRows)
            {
             // It is very possible  a target has been imaged more than once with different
             // equipment or focal lengths.  This checks to see what has been recorded of 
             // any of them, and if this one is not recorded.  It will be added.
                {
                    string strTelescope = TargetReader["ATI_Telescope_Lens_Used"].ToString();
                    string strArrayValue = arrEquipment[i].ToString();
                    if (strTelescope == arrEquipment[i])
                    {
                        result = true;
                        conn.Clone();
                        return result;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
            result = false;
            conn.Clone();
            return result;
        }
          
       
        result = false;
        conn.Clone();
        return result;
    }
   

}
```

If I find that the target has not already been stored in the DB, I then insert it using the code below.

```
       public void BuildATI(string strTargetName, string strMount, string strICamera, string strTelescope, string strFilter, string strGuidCamera, string strGuideScope)
       {
           using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
           {
               conn.Open();
               bool result = false;
               string strInsert = ("INSERT INTO Astro_Target_Imaged");
               string strColumns = "(ATI_TargetName, ATI_Mount_Used, ATI_Image_Camera, ATI_Telescope_Lens_Used, ATI_Filter, ATI_Guide_Camera, ATI_Guide_Scope_Used)";
               string strValues = "VALUES (@Target, @Mount, @ICamera, @Telescope, @Filter, @GCamera, @GScope)";
               string strQuery = strInsert + strColumns + strValues;   
               SQLiteCommand command =
                    new SQLiteCommand(strQuery, conn);
               command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Target", strTargetName));
               command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Mount", strMount));
               command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ICamera", strICamera));
               command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Telescope", strTelescope));
               command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Filter", strFilter));
               command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@GCamera", strGuidCamera));
               command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@GScope", strGuideScope));
               //.FirstOrDefault();

               try
               {
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   //conn.Commit();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   throw new Exception(ex.Message);
               }
                           
               conn.Clone();
           }


       }
   }
```

My problem is, for what ever reason after I perform the insert which I have walked through in debug and received no errors.  The insert throws no exceptions. But when I do a query against it in SqliteStudio, I don't see it.  So, I then rerun the same data through which goes through the very same check code where the if statement says it has rows.  But then, when I try to access a column in the table.  It throws an exception, no rows found.  Which is why I think I wacked the DB.

So, my question is.  Cuyrrently I have no commit statement in the code after the insert statment.  Every other type of db I have ever used(oracle, mysql, sql server).  You always commit.  Shoot, when I use the sqlitestudio.  I have to do commits.  Which is one of the reason I think I wacked the indexes.

So, my question is.  Indexed wacked in the db?  And what is the syntex for a commit against sqlite?

Any help would be most appriceated.

Dan

Comment: c# v3 is a very old tag...

Comment: This is probably for SQLite v3, not C# v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not closed the connection!

> **[Open Method (SQLLiteCOnnection)](https://docs.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/Devart.Data.SQLite%7EDevart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection%7EOpen.html)**
> Note: If the SQLiteConnection goes out of scope, the connection it represents does not close automatically. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close.

If you do not `.Close();` the connection, then it remains open, when it does eventually timeout or is closed from the server any un-comitted changes from that connection will be lost.

In your code you are incorrectly calling `.Clone()` instead of `.Close()`!

```
    result = true;
    conn.Clone();
    return result;
```

For read operations you won't really notice this, but for writes, your changes will never be committed.

---

As explained here: [transactional sqlite? in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/923749/1690217) and in [SQLite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)

In V3, `SQLiteConnection.Commit()` was removed and the connection is expected to operate in *AutoCommit* mode. You are however encouraged to use transaction scopes and transactions.

In *AutoCommit* mode, a transaction is created for the lifetime of the connection but it is only *committed* when the connection is deliberately *closed* using the call to `SQLiteConnection.Close();`

To start using transactions, your code should look like this:

```
   public void BuildATI(string strTargetName, string strMount, string strICamera, string strTelescope, string strFilter, string strGuidCamera, string strGuideScope)
   {
       using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
       using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
       {
           conn.Open(); // dont forget to close!
           bool result = false;
           string strInsert = ("INSERT INTO Astro_Target_Imaged");
           string strColumns = "(ATI_TargetName, ATI_Mount_Used, ATI_Image_Camera, ATI_Telescope_Lens_Used, ATI_Filter, ATI_Guide_Camera, ATI_Guide_Scope_Used)";
           string strValues = "VALUES (@Target, @Mount, @ICamera, @Telescope, @Filter, @GCamera, @GScope)";
           string strQuery = strInsert + strColumns + strValues;   
           SQLiteCommand command =
                new SQLiteCommand(strQuery, conn);
           command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Target", strTargetName));
           command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Mount", strMount));
           command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ICamera", strICamera));
           command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Telescope", strTelescope));
           command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Filter", strFilter));
           command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@GCamera", strGuidCamera));
           command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@GScope", strGuideScope));
           //.FirstOrDefault();

           try
           {
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               trans.Commit();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               // TODO:  for more complex logic you might consider rollback here
               // trans.Rollback();

               // NOTE: SQLiteConnection supports Rollback too!
               conn.Rollback()
               throw;
           }
                       
           conn.Close(); // explicitly close any connection you open!
       }
   }
```

If you are deliberately calling `.Commit();` on the enclosing transaction, then it is not strictly necessary to call `.Close();`, that would effectively rollback any commands executed since the call to `.Commit();` which in this example are none.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the conn.clone instead of the conn.close. I had seen that previously, but I had never included it in the commit to the repository and missed it in follow-up code recoveries I did.  I am going to have and come back to all the code and clean it up after I finish with all the utility functions, I am trying to incorporate into the app.  Thank you for your help.  Dan